# String Template with visit making a expr

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, tree-traversal, stringtemplate

I need to print a AST with String Template, so I am doing ST for the left and right size, and I am thinking about to make a stack for my STs, and later make a pop for print. I don't know if what I have is correct.

```
ST ast;
public void visit(Add expr){
    expr.getLeft().accept();
    ST aux_left = ast;
    expr.getRight().accept();
    ST aux_Right = ast;
    ast = gr.getInstanceOf("Add");
    ast.add("d","aux_left");
}
```

Comment: Please tell us which language you are using, and add the corresponding tag.

Comment: is java, and just string template i think

Comment: What order traversal? Post? Pre? If you are printing there is no need to stack anything just print as you go no?

Comment: my input is something like 2+4*9*3, i am doing a ast for this, so i want to see if my ast is correct, so i will print this again, i am thinking about to put this in a stack, every token, and later i will take this tokens, i want to print in a lot of ways, like ++* 2 4 9 3...

Comment: @DeiseKelley, the concept of using the stack is feasible but it would read as a flat model and would not reflect the Tree hierarchy necessarily. If you are good with that give it a try.